# How to send data by jquery ajax making beauty url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a REST service in the url: **`http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/api/route/{id}`**

I want to call the URL using JQuery AJAX, like:

```
function myFunc(id){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/api/route/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
}
```

I would like to send the id to the URL stay this way: **`http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/api/route/10`**

But if I use the data attribute It did not work, the only way is concatenating the url + id?

Comment: I guess you need 'data' parameter, so you have something like     url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/api/route/", data : { 'id' : id }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the format that you have done things, you would indeed have to concatenate the url and id like such:

```
function myFunc(id){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/api/route/"+id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
}
```